# Interface needs a different signature

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an interface with a signature like this:

```
Public Interface IOrphans
        Function getOrphans() As List(Of Integer)
End Interface
```

This interface is implemented by three classes.  I want to introduce a new class, but the interface needs to have an interface as follows:

```
Public Interface IOrphans
            Function getOrphans(ByVal strDataset As String) As List(Of Integer)
End Interface
```

Do I create a new interface called IDatasetOrphans or create an optional parameter.  Creating an optional parameter seems to go against SOLID principles.

Comment: Do you need to treat instances of `IDatasetOrphans` as `IOrphans`? If yes, inherit the interface and provide an override method. Do the classes that implement `IOrphans` need `IDatasetOrphans`? If no, go for the additional interface route. IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you needed the new method signature in all the places where you currently implement `IOrphans` then I would put it into your existing interface. If not then I would create a separate `IDatasetOrphans` interface with your new method signature and implement it where relevant.